# Will you be able to see the corona in a 90%+ partial eclipse?

Tags: the-sun, solar-eclipse

I live in Champaign, Illinois ([see map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Champaign,+IL/@40.11461,-88.34715,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x880cd08dde97691b:0x30f57847b475bfcf!8m2!3d40.1164204!4d-88.2433829)) and am planning to watch the August 21<sup>st</sup> solar eclipse. This community is within the 95% totality range, but not within the path of totality. Will I be able to see the Baily's beads, and more importantly **will I be able to see the corona**?

Comment: See also [Will I be able to see the Baily's Beads at 99%+ totality ?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/22145/will-i-be-able-to-see-the-beads-of-baily-at-99-totality)